# How to get the current hour of the day in Android

Tags: android

I'm unable to find a simple way of finding the current hour of the day in my Android app.
I want to perform some conditional logic based on the current hour of the day such as greeting the user on launching the app with goood morning/afternoon/evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get whats the hour of the day right now by doing this:

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

and then using some condition checking you will conclude what you application has to say like morning , evening or afternoon

and you can make your app say whatever you have concluded using TTS instance like this:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.speak("Good Morning/evening/agternoon", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

also your class will have to **implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener**

and as you wish your app should greet user at the start you should write all this in `onCreate()` of your first activity

Comment: Glad that it helped you....and just try to put your code whatever way you were doing it earlier so that your question will not be down voted and will not be marked as broad question.

Comment: you can add your code to this question itself by editing it....